# How to sort content

Tags: algorithm

At the moment my flash game site is sorting content by "likes - dislikes + views / 10". So if a game has 20 views and 10 likes it will score 12. this dose not work very well for example if

Game A has 100 views and 10 likes

Game B has 10 views and 5 likes

Game C has 5 views and 5 likes

Game A will score 20 and has a 10% view to like rashio where as game B only has a score of 6 and a rashio of 50% game C is by far the best with a rashio of 100% but a score of 5.5

Comment: If your current algorithm does not work, you will need to define what characterizes a good algorithm in order for anyone to help you.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: You seem to want to sort them by ratio of likes to views - wouldn't `likes/views` work?

Comment: If you want some fancy alghorithm consider the one that [IMDB uses for its top 250 movies list](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top) (bottom of the page) - [Bayesian Average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_average).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put at the end that I wanted to know how to sort content by likes in rlashon to views

Answer (score 0):

One of the best answers that I am aware of for this problem is http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html.  You can improve it in various ways, but real improvements take a lot more sophistication.

Comment: Looks interesting but it returns a percentage I need an infrently assending value or the first game to get a pefitct score will go to the top and stay there

Comment: @Isi It is a statistical test.  There are an infinite number of possible values.  And a perfect score with little data won't get to the top.  To stay there you have to consistently prove you belong there.